# Why does the Linux virtual terminal support only 16 colors, by default?

Tags: colors, tty

Why does the Linux virtual terminal support only 16 colors, by default?
Is there a particular reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're using a framebuffer console, you're at the mercy of the VGA text mode console -- whose `color_table[]` only has 16 elements.

Comment: Even under fb, actual text is limited.  I believe that might be OPs question.

Comment: Indeed. The `color_table[]` still limits the palette to a max of 16 colors. There's also the limit imposed by the VT ESC codes. With a fb, one can get more than 16 colors on the screen at once, just not though the vt interface.

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer is that the first graphic cards where not able to display more than 16 colors at the same time, and often the screens where monochromes.

When coding a game, developers would limit graphics to 16 colors. See old games (1985-1990) color usage for example.

A fun thing is that the firsts animated computer art was often done by cycling on some colors in a color table. The modern equivalent of this can be found here : [Canvas Cycle](http://www.effectgames.com/demos/canvascycle/).

Since *nix is all about retro-compatibility and POSIX norm... you can guess where this limitation come from.